# 3D Rotation as a Projective Transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, projective-geometry

I have a 8-parameter projective transformation, which maps a unit square into a quadrilateral on the plane (green).

[image]

Now, I want to "rotate the image by 120 degrees in 3D around the local Y axis" (red). So I need a 8-parameter projective transformation, which maps the unit square into that new quadrilateral.

I can create a 3D rotation matrix. My idea was to "turn it" into a projective transform, and combine with the previous transform, but how do I turn it into a projective transform?

=========================

By a Projective Transformation, I mean a matrix M 3x3, bottom right value is 1. It maps from a plane to a plane this way:

```
Z    := (M[3,1]*x + M[3,2]*y + M[3,3]);
newX := (M[1,1]*x + M[1,2]*y + M[1,3]) / Z;
newY := (M[2,1]*x + M[2,2]*y + M[2,3]) / Z;
```

Comment: Your question is not clear.  Can you specify in plain English how you obtain the green quadrilateral from the square, and can you show the square and the produced quadrilateral in the image that you attach to your problem.

Comment: I have added a description of how my Projective Transformation works.

Comment: Your transformations map the plane to itself. The $y$ axis lies in the plane. If the "local $y$ axis" also lies in the plane I don't see how you can possibly construct a $120$-degree rotation around that axis, as the result would be outside the original plane. It is also unclear from the picture what kind of $120$-degree rotation you think you are performing. Can you label the vertices of your quadrilaterals with their $(x,y)$ coordinates, and also specify which vertex of the green quadrilateral was rotated to each vertex of the red one?

Comment: My 2D quadrilateral corresponds to "some 3D quadrilateral", which is projected on the plane. I would like to "rotate that 3D version" around some of its "3D axes". But I don't know how to do that in terms of 2D projections.